# Can wireless credential information be save with a guest user account

Tags: networking, wireless, guest-session

What I have are laptops that have a customized user account and can auto-login and auto-launch Firefox browser. So the next step is I want to do is to lock down this user account. However, if I do lock it down, the end user will have to login into the wireless network every time the laptop reboots.

What I want to do is to lock down the customized user account like the guess account, while letting the end user to save the wireless network information.

*Is this possible?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no…  They will have to type the password every time for their home network.

I just tested this out in my guest account by trying to connect to my guest network (which I never have defined before, as it's for guests)

The problem is the key-ring: Ubuntu will want to store the password in a key-ring, and even if they create one, the key-ring will be deleted upon exit, so you cannot lock it down as tight as a guest session if you want the end-users to be able to connect to their home network *and* save their password.

*On the other hand, depending on your use-case, this might be a "security feature": **as long as it's documented it's not a bug, right?***

Comment: The guest account works great in Kiosk with Ethernet LAN network connection. With a mobile laptop, we want it to be able to connect to wireless and stay connected after reboot. It would be a nice feature to have.

Comment: We did test out an Android latptop, and it is able to lock down to the browser only, and let user connect to different Wi-Fi. The only thing we didn't like it was the resolution inside the Citrix session was too low, and we weren't able to adjust it.

Comment: The original question was: "Can it be done in the guest session?" and the answer to that one you have...  "How to lock down a normal session like a guest session while still being able to save NetworkManager changes?" would be [another question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: All of these get me start thinking another approach: create an account with access to Firefox browser only, but nothing else, not even command shells. Is it possible? (I think it is, but don't know how. Let me research first). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the connection using your normal account, and make sure *All users may connect to this network* is checked:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. These are laptops for users to take home. It means I have no way of knowing what Wi-Fi network they are going to join. I want the end user to have the ability to make their own selection of Wi-Fi, but nothing else. Thanks though

Comment: @ByronZhao These "guest" accounts are not the normal guest accounts, right? So the users can also pick the same option while connecting.

Comment: Well, I want the normal guest account. What I mean by that is I want to lock down these user account to make them like guest account, so that the end users are not able to save files or make change to these laptops. All these laptops are for them to connect to our Citrix environment while we don't want to spend time and work to maintain these laptops. But if I indeed lock down these accounts, I still want them to have the ability to connect to any Wi-Fi they want, and the Wi-Fi credential can be saved to the laptop so that they don't need to re-enter it every time they are rebooted.

Comment: @ByronZhao I think this will work even then, since the configuration will be saved by Network Manager, not in the user's directories.